# Nested Query on Array in MongoDB collection

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have below User collection and I want find/update query to update nested array elements.

```
{
_id:"000-0000-0001",
Roles :{
         0000-0000-0011: //EngagementId
        ["0000-0000-0111", "0000-0000-0112", "0000-0000-3333"],//RoleId
         "0000-0000-0012" : 
        ["0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112"]
       }
},
{

_id:"000-0000-0002",
Roles :{
         "0000-0000-0021" : [ "0000-0000-0222", "0000-0000-0112"],
         "0000-0000-0022" : [ "0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112"],
         "0000-0000-0022" : [ "0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112", "0000-0000-3333"]
       }
}
```

Requirement: I want to pull RoleId 0000-0000-3333 if the array have combination of 0000-0000-3333 and 0000-0000-0112

Below is expected result :

```
{
_id:"000-0000-0001",
Roles :{
         "0000-0000-0011" : ["0000-0000-0111", "0000-0000-0112"],
         "0000-0000-0012" : ["0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112"]
       }
},
{

_id:"000-0000-0002"
Roles :{
         "0000-0000-0021" : [ "0000-0000-0222", "0000-0000-0112"],
         "0000-0000-0022" : [ "0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112"],
         "0000-0000-0022" : [ "0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112"]
       }
}
```

Note : Find/update will work on Key:value or if it is nested then key.key:value, but in above example we have key.value.[values]:$pull(value) and that's the challaenge.

Comment: Can you change your data model?  If so, wouldn't something like `"roles": [ {"engagementId": "0000-0000-0021", "roleIds": ["0000-0000-0222", "0000-0000-0112"]}, {"engagementId": "0000-0000-0022", "roleIds": ["0000-0000-0121", "0000-0000-0112"]} ]` make future queries easier?

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs, Thank you for the reply and suggestions. I understand that structure is not good but this is existing collection and I cant change it now.

Comment: Would you edit your question and update your documents?  Currently it's not valid JSON/BSON.  Also, would you show the output that you want?

Comment: Once again Thanks @rickhg12hs, I have updated. Please check and let me know.

Comment: With quotes  (`"`) it's OK, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OWw4Mxl8hi0).  Is the mongoplayground.net configuration accurate?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, Yes its correct in mongoplayground.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model necessitates a complicated `update` with a pipeline.

Here' one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "Roles": {"$exists": true}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "Roles": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {"$objectToArray": "$Roles"},
            "as": "roleKV",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$roleKV.k",
              "v": {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$and": [
                      {"$in": ["0000-0000-0112", "$$roleKV.v"]},
                      {"$in": ["0000-0000-3333", "$$roleKV.v"]}
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$roleKV.v",
                      "cond": {"$ne": ["$$this", "0000-0000-3333"]}
                    }
                  },
                  "$$roleKV.v"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gbrx1wDqAF5).